# Nullability of reference types in return type doesn't match overridden member

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm using an API that returns JSON where one of its values can be either `false` or an object. To handle that, I've created a custom [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.1).

```cs
internal class JsonFalseOrObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : class
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the following compiler error:

> Possible null reference return.

I could set the returned type to be a `T?` but then I would get the error:

> Nullability of reference types in return type doesn't match overridden member.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Reference types are *inherently* nullable. Only value types (wich are usually implemented as structs) need to be given it explicitly.

Comment: The error message tells you taht you are not *allowed* to return null from this function, as the function you are overriding does not allow null return values. I think we will need to see the function you are overriding here.

Comment: I should have specified that I have enabled the nullable reference types from C# 8. The method I'm overriding is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read

Comment: You should rethink what you're doing. No matter the converter, an API that returns arbitrary values for the *same* attribute will confuse *every* client. A `false` is a very specific JSON value too, not `null` or a missing value. If you can't change the API, consider returning a new `T`"empty"  instance instead of null.

Comment: In fact, it's *because* `false` isn't null that this method is called - if the value was `null` or missing, the converter wouldn't be called. You should reconsider the mapping. Perhaps the target type can be a *struct* whose `default` can be treated as a missing value? The type could have an `IsMissing` property that's false by default and set when a real value is used.

Comment: You could use an `Option <T>` type like the one described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648767/how-to-deal-with-optional-arguments-when-wanting-to-enable-nullable-reference-ty) or [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38121), combined with pattern matching and return `None` when the attribute is `false`

Comment: Indeed the API is really confusing but I can't change anything about that. I think I'll go with Jeff's answer because I'm looking for the simpliest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stated that the generic type is a (non-nullable) `T` yet you are returning `null`. That clearly cannot be valid.

You would need to make your converter implement `JsonConverter<T?>` or use the null forgiving operator if you just don't care.

```
internal class JsonFalseOrObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T?> where T : class
{
    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or

```
public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
    {
        return null!;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Both solutions work fine but I'm really confused.

For the first one, isn't T? equivalent to Nullable<T> which is a nullable struct? How can you make the difference between a nullable ref and a nullable struct? Why T? is allowed here but not here `JsonFalseOrConverter<T?>`?

For the second, how can the compiler allow a null-forgiving on a literal null. Isn't the purpose of the operator to tell the compiler "don't worry it's not null".

Comment: `T?` is only equivalent to `Nullable<T>` iff T is a value type. In your example, it was constrained to a reference type. No special type is created for nullable reference types, the compiler just does additional checks for you to ensure that any code referencing the types are consistent with its nullability. In general, you won't be able to share the same generic class between nullable value types and nullable reference types, the compiler will have to generate separate classes anyway.

Comment: The null forgiving operator allows you to tell the compiler that even though the expected type is a non-nullable reference, you're saying that you want to use a nullable value here and the compiler shouldn't warn about it. Behind the scenes, everything is still the same reference type, only the compiler is more or less strict with how you use it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to `return null!` :

```
#nullable enable

internal class JsonFalseOrObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : class
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
        {
            return null!;
        }
        else
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader);
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options){}
}
```

Reference classes *are* nullable so the compiler just uses `T` when `T?` is encountered.

A better option would be to create something similar to F#'s [Option type](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/), that contains Some value if a value is set, None if the value is false. By making that `Option` a struct, we get a default `None` value even when the property is missing or null :

```
readonly struct Option<T> 
{
    public readonly T Value {get;}

    public readonly bool IsSome {get;}
    public readonly bool IsNone =>!IsSome;

    public Option(T value)=>(Value,IsSome)=(value,true);    

    public void Deconstruct(out T value)=>(value)=(Value);
}

//Convenience methods, similar to F#'s Option module
static class Option
{
    public static Option<T> Some<T>(T value)=>new Option<T>(value);    
    public static Option<T> None<T>()=>default;
}
```

The deserializer can return `None()` or `default` if false is encountered:

```
internal class JsonFalseOrObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter<Option<T>> where T : class
{
    public override Option<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
        {
            return Option.None<T>(); // or default
        }
        else
        {
            return Option.Some(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader));
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Option<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case Option<T> (_    ,false) :
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer,false,options);
                break;
            case Option<T> (var v,true) :
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer,v,options);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Write` method shows how `Option<T>` can be handled using pattern matching.

Using this serializer, the following classes :

```
class Category
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}


class Product
{
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public Option<Category> Category {get;set;}
}
```

Can be serialized with `false` generated for missing categories :

```
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{ 
    Converters = { new JsonFalseOrObjectConverter<Category>() }
};

var product1=new Product{Name="A"};
var json=JsonSerializer.Serialize(product1,serializerOptions);
```

This returns :

```
{"Name":"A","Category":false}
```

Deserializing this string returns a `Product` whose `Category` is an `Option<Category>` without a value :

```
var product2=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product>(json,serializerOptions);
Debug.Assert(product2.Category.IsNone);
```

Pattern matching expressions can be used to extract and use the Category's properties if it has a value, eg :

```
string category=product2.Category switch { Option<Category> (_    ,false) =>"No Category",
                                        Option<Category> (var v,true)  => v.Name};
```

Or

```
if(product2.Category is Option<Category>(var cat,true))
{
    Console.WriteLine(cat.Name);
}
```